# Intellij Light bulb

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Is there a way to get light bulb to stay in the margins like in netbeans? Or at least a way to click on the highlighted code and get a fix menu instead of getting an information popup?

I don't like having to press alt enter each time to fix something so I want to be able to do this without pressing alt+enter and with clicking instead.

Answer (score 29):

There are 2 ways that I know of.

1. You can click on the **red line**, and click the **red bulb** that will appear near the start of the line.

[image: redbulb]

2. You can use the keyboard shortcut `Alt + Enter`(⌥⏎) to bring it up.

   - Click the red underlined area and press `Alt + Enter` (⌥⏎)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Clicking is not working for me but alt+enter works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your IntelliJ Preferences > Keymap > Add a shortcut to the "Show Intention Actions"

You'll get your suggestions instantly when you're on a bad piece of code. No need to click and wait for the light bulb to show up, that's too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how or if it's possible to have it always there but if I'm understanding you correctly the way to get the light bulbs to appear by using only the mouse and clicks is to click the highlighted or underlined code a single time and it should appear in the margins.

Here's some code highlighted and thus has some information:

[image]

Then you have the information when you hover:

[image]

But if I click inside the highlighted section I get the light bulb:

[image]

The same applies for things like unused methods which gives the menu to "Safe delete" and others. In that situation the code isn't highlighted but rather grayed out. No matter, click it and get the bulb.

As a user of drafting tools I understand that there's basically two camps of users. Those that favor a mouse and those who favor keyboard shortcuts. So my 0.02 is the shortcuts are just that. They're faster - zoom zoom!